# I want to use the apa bibliography style

Tags: apa-style

I am trying to use the APA style using apacite bibliography style. The bibliography is generated very well but my problem are the citation themselves in the actual document. They just show author names but not the year when I use the \cite command in the text. How can I solve this. I want to get something like this (author,year). But now, I am getting (author,)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: In addition to `apacite`, do you load any addition citation-related LaTeX packages? If the citation command you're using -- `\citeA`?, or `\citep` from the `natbib` package? -- generates something like `(author,)` instead of `(author,year)`, it is possible that there are errors (such as missing commas between bib fields, or a missing `year` field) in the entries affected by this problem. Please check the `.blg` (bibliography log) file for any error reports.

Comment: With no MWE, this is 'too localized'. Request reopening if more info is available.

Answer (score 0):

please add

```
    \usepackage[authoryear]{natbib} %author-year is actually the default for this package
```

When placing the following in the text they will lead to the afterparts

```
    % where jon90 is specified in the .bib
    \citet{jon90}     %  -->        Jones et al. (1990) 
    \citep{jon90}     %  -->        (Jones et al., 1990)
    \citet*{jon90}    %  -->        Jones, Baker, and Williams (1990)
    \citep*{jon90}    %  -->        (Jones, Baker, and Williams, 1990)
```

Note: this package easily works alongside the Bibtex package, I'm supposing you use it.

For more information:
Source: http://merkel.zoneo.net/Latex/natbib.php