# In text citations not appearing for APA citation

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I am working on my thesis, and need to have the references in APA style. The bibliography is generated correctly, but the in text citation are not appearing. All that shows up is "[]".

The main section of my code is basically:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{byustyle}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}}

\begin{document}
\include{chapters/intro}
\include{chapters/background}
\include{chapters/starCCM}
\include{chapters/testing}
\include{chapters/starNX}
\include{chapters/results}
\include{chapters/conclusion}

% REFERENCES
\cleardoublepage
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{sources}

% APPENDICES
\appendix
\include{appendix/appendixa}
\include{appendix/appendixb}
\end{document}
```

Within the chapters I do in text citations as \cite{citation1}

Is there something I'm missing for the APA style?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE . 
Have you tried using `\input` instead of `\include`?

Comment: Does this [question and answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/8528) address your problem?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It still compiled already when I made the change, but did not fix the citation issue.

Comment: EDIT: Sorry, but also thankfully, I was able to find the solution from this question:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66169/i-want-to-use-the-apa-bibliography-style?rq=1
I added \usepackage[authoryear]{natbib} before \usepackage{apacite} and changed the in text citations to \citep{} and \citet{}, and this fixed it perfectly. Thanks for the responses.